# apache-ignite-2.8.1 - Weird CPU load reported in Ignite log

Tags: ignite

The Ignite logs shows CPU usage showing 100% but the actual server CPU usage is below 25%. The log prints as below showing cur=100%. Do we have any metrics of CPU usage for Ignite ? The overall cpu usage of server is very low but still Ignite log shows 100%.

```
    [2021-10-12 21:04:01,936][INFO ][grid-timeout-worker-#23][IgniteKernal]
    Metrics for local node (to disable set 'metricsLogFrequency' to 0)
    Node [id=ec867e26, uptime=7 days, 14:00:43.668]
    H/N/C [hosts=8, nodes=60, CPUs=112]
    CPU [cur=100%, avg=5.69%, GC=118.3%]
    PageMemory [pages=862676]
    Heap [used=13339MB, free=6.95%, comm=14336MB]
    Off-heap [used=3389MB, free=67.53%, comm=3560MB]
    sysMemPlc region [used=0MB, free=99.21%, comm=40MB]
    TxLog region [used=0MB, free=100%, comm=40MB]
    Default_Region region [used=3388MB, free=66.91%, comm=3480MB]
    Outbound messages queue [size=146435]
    Public thread pool [active=0, idle=0, qSize=0]
    System thread pool [active=1, idle=7, qSize=0]
```

Comment: Look to the avg value, it's quite low. Looks like this CPU usage spike was issued due to GC (GC=118%). And YES Ignite has some metrics for CPU usage https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring-metrics/new-metrics#system

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a very high GC activity. Try to increase your heap (-Xmx).